# How to store Files on Shared network drive in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, network-drive

I have a Asp.net Application where i am attempting to save my files on a shared network drive.

```
 StrPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\\server\c\DTA\");
```

But i get an error unable to find path

What should be done is it possible to save files in a shared network drive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MapPath is used to map a virtual path of your webserver to a physical path on the hard drive. What you have is already a physical path, so you can just use it to create the file directly.

```
var fileStream = File.Create(@"\\server\c\DTA\");
...
```